# SQL конвертация mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss в timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Как сконвертировать дату формата -- 24/12/2021 09:06:16 в timestamp (или другой формат который позволит сделать сортировку) ?
Так как сортировка или функции min max c данным форматом в SQLite и MySQL не работают

Answer (score 0):

MySQL не знаю, но на MS SQL это можно было бы сделать так:

```
DECLARE @DT char(19) = '24/12/2021 09:06:16'

SELECT CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@DT, 7, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(@DT, 4, 2), '-', SUBSTRING(@DT, 1, 2), ' ', SUBSTRING(@DT, 12, 8)) AS datetime)
```

Суть: вытащить из строки все части даты и собрать их в валидную строку, после чего привести к нужному типу данных функцией CAST. Подставь вместо @DT сdой столбец и замени функции CONCAT и SUBSTRING на аналоги в MySQL.